# What is using my memory on my Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am currently running a single GPU Cluster Compute node on Amazon EC2 which is listed as having 22 GB of RAM per instance. `top` confirms that the instance does indeed have 22 GB of RAM but on an idle systems it appears that 5-6 GB of RAM are consistently in use. Neither `top` nor `ps aux` can identify the processes to which this usage is attributable.

5-6 GB seems too large for the OS to me, but perhaps I am wrong. Could this be an overhead due to virtualization on Amazon? Any other ideas or suggestions as to how I could track this down?

Comment: Are you including the memory cache in this calculation? It might be useful to show the contents of proc meminfo.

Answer (score 7):

When you look at **top**, the free memory you see is the value before kernel caching.

```
top - 12:59:25 up 1 day, 15:47,  5 users,  load average: 0.04, 0.10, 0.12
Tasks: 161 total,   1 running, 160 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  3.5%us,  1.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 94.2%id,  0.4%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3985464k total,  3369908k used,   615556k free,   752964k buffers
Swap:  1951740k total,       12k used,  1951728k free,  1439160k cached
```

My laptop as 3985464 kilo-bytes of memory total. But the linux kernel would cache most of that internally, so **top** only shows 619748kB of free memory.  But if you look at it using the **free** command, you understand that, in fact, most of the memory is available... in the cache.

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3985464    3365716     619748          0     752796    1439152
-/+ buffers/cache:    1173768    2811696
Swap:      1951740         12    1951728
```

The real free memory is the one shown on the **buffers/cache** line.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
-/+ buffers/cache:    1173768    2811696
```

This machine as 2.8GB of free memory.

Comment: This is pretty confusing since I guess I don't understand the role of the cache. What do you mean by _"the linux kernel would cache most of [total memory of 3985464k]"_? You state that `top` then _only shows_ another number, but _only shows_ means the other number will be less, yet the number you quote is greater. Insert head-scratch smiley here.

Answer (score 7):

The reason why you see a substantial amount of memory being used is that Linux is using much of it for file caching.

This would probably clarify things for you:

http://www.linuxatemyram.com/